# How to return additional information outside an array, in a list serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have the following serializer :

```
class SalesProjectListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
permissions = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_custompermissions',read_only=True)
class Meta:
    model = SalesProject
    fields = ['sales_project_id', 'sales_project_name',
              'sales_project_est_rev', 'project_status','permissions']
    depth = 2

def get_custompermissions(self, obj):
    permission_list = ['add_salesproject']
    user_perms = User.get_user_permissions(self.context['request'].user)
    return { permission: True if permission in user_perms else False for permission in permission_list }
```

This serializer is used to serialize the data thats used to render the project listing page.

The serialized data would give me something like :

```
 projects = [{sales_project_id : 1 , sales_project_name = 'test , ... ,permissions: [...]}]
```

However instead what i wish to return is somthing like this :

```
 projects = {projects:[{sales_project_id : 1 , sales_project_name = 'test , ... }]
            ,permissions: [...]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cand override the method responsible for the response depending on your View type.

I assume you are using a `ListAPIView` so this is how you would do it:

```
class YourView(ListAPIView):
    model = SalesProject
    serializer_class = SalesProjectListSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(self.get_queryset(), many=True)

        # change the data
        # serializer.data is the response that your serializer generates
        res = {"projects": serializer.data}
    
        return Response(res)
```

It's the same for other views such as `RetrieveAPIView` but you should override the `retrieve` method instead.